# What shortcut key combination zooms in Photoshop on a Japanese Keyboard?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm on Windows with a Japanese keyboard. The normal zoom in for photoshop is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> but on a Japanese keyboard the <kbd>+</kbd> requires pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> so pressing it in Photoshop does not work. With or without shift it doesn't work.

What key combination works for "Zoom In" on Japanese keyboard on Windows?

[image]

note: here is the configuration screen

[image]

I can change the configuration to a custom key of course and get it to work but it should be working without configuration. It should be noted that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> does not work either where as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> for zoom out does work.

Note: I know I can alt scroll wheel to zoom. I also know I can click the zoom tool. I know I can open the navigator and use the slider at the bottom. My question is specifically about the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: The plus symbol requires Shift on every keyboard as far as I am aware - certainly on my British English keyboard. But you don't need to press Shift when using the Photohsop shortcut.  Perhaps the problem lies elsewhere?  Have you tried editing the keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Pressing `ctrl +` is not working. Neither is  `shift ctrl +` nor any other combination involving `+`. I have tried editing the keys. I pressed `ctrl +` and it showed up as `ctrl ;` but told me that was already assigned to something else. Similarly it told me `shift ctrl ;` is already assigned to something else. For the time being I assigned it to some other key but it should work so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: On a British English keyboard, the + symbol is actually above the = symbol on the same key.  So perhaps if you try Shift+= then it might work. Failing that, contact Adobe or post on Adobe's help forum.

Comment: I just had a look on youtube about Japanese keyboard input methods, and [one of the videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=207&v=u3ZuELh7rhI) mentions that sometimes shortcuts don't work unless you change the input language to English, otherwise the computer will try to input a Japanese character.

Comment: I would be ridiculous if Japanese users had to switch to English to use Photoshop. That said, the [these docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/jp/photoshop/how-to/use-shortcut-keys-for-efficiency-photoshop.html) also claim `Ctrl +` is supposed to work

Comment: I don't disagree with you. Yes it does sound ridiculous.

Comment: Can't you check what hotkey is assigned for zoom in/out in View menu?

Comment: Yes, it says `Ctrl +` Can post a screenshot tomorrow (not at that comptuer right now)

Comment: This won't fix the problem with the shortcut, however it might be worthwhile mentioning that I almost never use that shortcut for zooming.  Instead I use a mouse with a centre scroll wheel, and press Alt and scroll up and down for zooming in and out of Photoshop documents.  I often have to zoom in and out since I do quite a bit of retouching.

Comment: This has existed since the dawn of time in Adobe products and affects non-English keyboards that require modifier keys to type out certain symbols. Like you said, you press the modifier key combination required to output + but it thinks you are pressing shift+ctrl+; instead and therefore it won't work, unless you make that the new shortcut.. As far as I know, there is no proper way to fix it. You can: change the shortcut (if possible. In this case yes.), find another way to do the same thing (ctrl+space+mouse click or drag - add alt modifier to zoom out) or script it.

Comment: That said... I've never tested if downloading Finnish language pack, in my case, would solve the issue. I've only used PS with finnish language once.... but PS might understand your keyboard layout better if it uses the same language....maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>mouse scroll wheel</kbd> to zoom in and out in Photoshop.